# Why kill makes a bash script exit

Tags: bash, kill

after the kill statement the script prints "Terminated" and the following lines never get executed:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill -9 `ps -ef | grep MailSender | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
echo starting
./MailSender
```

I have even tried to add `set +e` at the beginning but it still exits after kill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the name of your script include `MailSender`? Try changing it, if so. Also, use `pkill -9`, it'll be cleaner:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill -9 MailSender
echo starting
./MailSender
```

Comment: Why not using pkill directly? :)
(And - why -9? 'kill -kill' is so harmful...)

Comment: Guess I didn't optimise the code far enough, thanks :-) I'm hoping this is a last-resort script, so I didn't argue with the use of `SIGKILL`. Admittedly, I have used to kill processes when they would lockup but still absort `SIGTERM`s so there might still be a genuine use to script it.

Comment: pkill doesnt work, I guess its because MailSender is an argument: /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono /etc/sender/MailSender.exe

Comment: And if you are under Solaris, don't use `killall`, which would work the same as `pkill` under Linux but literally kill *all* processes under Solaris.

Comment: But this worked: kill -9 `pgrep -f "MailSender.exe"`. Thanks!

Comment: @Dawkins You should be able to do `pkill -f "Mailsender.exe"`

Comment: WARNING about using pkill: the -v parameter does something else than what one would normally expect a -v flag to do, and does so very tersely indeed..... "something else" is extremely destructive.

Comment: `-v` is consistent with all the grep family: it negates the resultset. Who is using `-v` here? I don't follow.

Comment: In my case the script's full path had the process name I was trying to kill.

Answer (score -1):

pkill will kill anything contained MailSender, maybe your script contain MailSender in its name. Change it.

Comment: No improvement over accepted answer.